# Can I append a Javascript string to an HTML head element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add some Javascript to a HTML head like this:

```
var scriptInjection = "&lt;script type='text/javascript'/&gt;function toggleVisibility() {$('#ivuFrm_page0ivu1').contents().find('.tableContentRow').toggle()}&lt;/script/&gt;";
$('#ivuFrm_page0ivu1').contents().find("head").each(function(){
        console.log($(this).prop("tagName"))
        $(this).append(scriptInjection);
        });
```

This is only appending a string though and not the script element. How can I resolve this?

Comment: that's because you're not inserting html. you're inserting a text node. `&lt;` means nothing to JS. if it was `"<script...>"`, then it'd be seen as html. ditto for `&gt;`

Comment: Create a script tag with document.createElement().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = "function toggleVisibility() {$('#ivuFrm_page0ivu1').contents().find('.tableContentRow').toggle()};";
$(this).append(script);
```

Comment: This worked thanks I will except when time is up. Yet I still receive a "toggleVisibility is not defined" error if i click on the button in the body with the onClick = 'toggleVisibility()'. Any ideas on that?

Comment: You probably have to rebind the function to the button After you insert the extra script tags, since the button won't refer to your new function yet.

Comment: shouldn't $.append() already create the element if passed a string? i think it just needs un-encoded.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery:

```
$('head').append(
    '<script>' +
        'function toggleVisibility() {' +
            '$(\'#ivuFrm_page0ivu1\').contents().find(\'.tableContentRow\').toggle()' +
        '}' +
    '<\/script>'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
// if (this.readyState == 'complete') { callFunctionFromScript(); }
}
script.src = 'your/path/to/-script.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: OP doesn't have an external script, adding via and dom methods won't execute the textContent, jquery internally uses eval() to do that.

Answer (score 0):

using vanilla js (no jquery)

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("GET", "/yourpath/toyourfile.html", true);
ajaxInicial.onreadystatechange = function () {if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.responseText);}}
ajaxInicial.send();
```